# Correct design for certain methods

Tags: java, selenium, testing

Consider you have a class `RunMe`. As the name supposes it is ran by another class. Let's asume through `RunMe.run()`.

`RunMe` has a private variable with Data that it uses to run different Tests, lets call ist `data`.
Let's say this data is initialized by `RunMe.initialize()`.

After that, in the `run()` Method, the first Test is ran with the default values set by the `initialize` function for `data`. Let's call that test-method `testWithDefaultValues`.

We now want to fill our `data` with some custom data. Let's say we do this using `fillData`.

Then we want to execute another test using our newly filled data. Let's call this test `testWithFilledData`.

Our run-method at this point would look something like this

```
public void run() {
  initialize();
  testWithDefaultValues();
  fillData();
  testWithFilledData();
}
```

Can you see how akward this code looks? It looks AND feels wrong. A thing directly coming into my mind: The only reason `testWithFilledData()` or also `testWithDefaultValues()`is actually doing what the name supposes is because of the order in which these functions are called in `run`. This has to be wrong.

So instead i should eliminate `initialize` and `fillData` and do what those functions do in the according test-function?

What if you consider the fact that many more test-functions are going to exist, each of them testing with a different set of data, all of which have to be quite manually filled (`data.setField("fooField","fooValue);`).

**Can someone possibly give a general construct or idea in which he would explain how he would solve the given task properly?**

Right now i am really struggeling to find a pattern that "feels nice" and correct. What i am doing currently must be wrong.

Edit: Worth mentioning is that the test-function cannot be generic. For every different variations of `data` different results have to be considered.

Comment: Why would you call a class `RunMe`? What do instances of the class do?

Comment: The class is not actually called RunMe, it was just an example. It is part of a Selenium Test-Suite. Another class is supposed to run a whole number of Selenium-Tests (for all logical procedures that exist on the Website). Each class (Such as RunMe in this exmaple) is illustrating such test.

So the class is not testing itself, the class IS the test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what would happen if you attempt to call `testWithDefaultValues()` without calling `initialize()` first? You won't actually be testing with the default values, you will be testing with whatever you previously set data to. I think you should move away from modifying the internal test data in the actual test functions, and perhaps rather have a generic test function that has `data` passed into it.

This makes a lot of sense if `testWithDefaultValues()` and `testWithFilledData()` are actually doing the same thing but with different data.

I think something like this makes more sense:

```
Data testData = getTestData();
test(testData);
Data fillData = getFillData();
test(fillData);
```

Comment: Yep, that's what i saw. However, consider that you have to test the set of data for say 20 different variations of data. Would you create 20 different versions of functions that 20 different data-sets?
Also test() cannot be generic. I failed to mention that. Each test has to consider different results. The function testWithDefaultValues() has to consider different than testWithFilledData();

Comment: Even if it cannot be generic, you really shouldn't be dependent on an internal data property that other test methods can modify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should fill only one method with all the code needed for the test you are trying to achieve. You are then able to fill the `variables` or `data` for your test accordingly and stage different values for your `data` to run different test starting always from the same method.

With this simple construct, you are able to create multiple tests method and won't get lost in your code.

**EDIT**

You should always consider a test method like a blackbox testing. If you consider that you have no idea what's the code running inside the method. All you have to care about is the `input` and `output` of you test.

If the same method should produce different `output` based on different `input`. The code inside your blackbox remains the same.

However, if your method needs to interact differently with the `input` to generate the `output` you need, then, you need to consider writing a different test.

My two cents, hope it helps

Comment: This would definitely be the proper way of doing it, but please consider my Edit. I failed to mention that each test-function will have to check for different results, depending on the way `data`is filled.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Template Method design pattern to create a test framework. You'd probably be better off using a mature test framework like JUnit.

```
public abstract class TestCase {
    // This is the template method.
    public final boolean execute() {
        initTest();
        return runTest();
    }

    // Init hook method.
    public abstract void initTest();

    // Test logic hook method.
    public abstract boolean runTest();
}

public abstract class BaseTest extends TestCase {
    public boolean runTest() {
        // This is the common execution for different data sets...
    }
}

public Test1 extends BaseTest {
    public void initTest() {
        // Data init for test 1...
    }
}
```

You can extend `BaseTest` for each test data set you have. To run the tests:

```
new Test1().execute();
new Test2().execute();
```

EDIT: You can of course skip `BaseTest` if you don't have common test logic. Or you can tailor the template method to add more hooks for whatever makes sense for your particular needs. The main point is to capture the common process in the template method, to isolate common code in some hook methods, and to provide unique concrete overrides in other hook methods.